# Communicating between MainActivity and a Retained Fragment after configuration change

Tags: android, multithreading, orientation, handler

I have a thread running an infinite loop in a very similar manner to the common Game Loop programming pattern. The thread (called `AudioScheduler`) and `MainActivity` communicate via handlers. I now need to get the app to deal with configuration changes destroying and recreating `MainActivity` while `AudioScheduler` keeps running.

There are numerous ways to go about this. It looks like the currently recommended best method is using a Retained Fragment approach as shown in the API demos and as discussed in [Alex Lockwood's excellent article](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html).

In his example he effectively has one way communication from his `AsyncTask` to his `MainActivity` by using an interface. In my situation I need my MainActivity to communicate UI changes to my AudioScheduler thread, and for my AudioScheduler thread to also be able communicate back to the MainActivity to tell it to make updates to the UI.

I've used handlers to achieve this, but is it the best method and will it work with the Retained Fragment approach to configuration changes?

**My current communication approach**

In my `AudioScheduler` thread I have;

- created a handler `audioSchedulerHandler`
- created a getter method so that MainActivity can access it:

  ```
      public Handler getHandler() {return audioSchedulerHandler;}
  ```
- used a constructor which takes a handler from the Parent activity which it can use to communicate back with:

  ```
  public AudioScheduler(Handler parentHandler) {mParentHandler = parentHandler;}
  ```

In my `MainActivity` I have;

- created a handler `mainHandler`
- passed this to the constructor when I create an instance of `AudioScheduler`
- used my `getHandler()` method on the `AudioScheduler` instance so it can be communicated with.

I will need to re-establish this two way communication any time `MainActivity` has been destroyed and recreated. How should this be done?

I can add a method `setParentHandler(Handler parentHandler)` to the `AudioScheduler` class so my `mParentHandler` can still be reassigned after the thread object has already been created. The newly created MainActivity can also call the getHandler() method each time, to get the `AudioScheduler`'s handler. But when should these be called?

Modifying Alex Lockwood's example would I override `MainActivity`'s onCreate something like shown below, and would this cause any problems?

```
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    mTaskFragment = (TaskFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag("audioSchedulerTask");

    if (mTaskFragment != null) {
      // Fragment is non-null, so it has been retained across a configuration change.

      // TODO: Use the getHandler() and setParentHandler() methods to re-establish communication.

    } else {
      // Fragment is null, so make a new one.

      mTaskFragment = new TaskFragment();
      fm.beginTransaction().add(mTaskFragment, "task").commit();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Have you considered putting your `AudioScheduler` in a `Service` or something like that? If your thread is going to persist over a long period of time (and not just several seconds, as was the case in my post), usually a `Service` is something to think about.

Comment: Also on an unrelated note, you may want to check out the [**`HandlerThread`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread.html) class (since it might reduce the amount of complicated stuff you have to do with `Handler`s etc.). Just letting you know that exists (I'm not actually sure if you want to use one in your situation or not).

Comment: Thanks for responding Alex, and no I was not aware of HandlerThread. Thanks for the tip! Regarding the multithreading, I'm still trying to get my head round what approach works best when. My thread is basically checking the state of a set of objects at a fixed frame rate (20 fps) and firing off messages to the UI and other threads based on the results. It's for an audio production tool, but the infinite loop checking object states at a set frame rate is essentially identical to the game loop paradigm. Considering this extra info do you think using a Thread is reasonable in this case? Cheers.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to put @Alex in my previous response. BTW if a Thread is reasonable, is the way I've suggested re-establishing the handler communication overlooking anything, or would it be best to go with interfaces?